# How can I safely jar up my homemade salad dressing?

Tags: food-safety

I'm wanting to jar up my favorite House dressing made with miracle whip, so I can sell it and give it away. I want to make sure I do it safely!

Comment: Are you trying to make it safe at room temperature?

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to sell it, you need to consider "legally" as well as "safely" (here, as in a number of situations, they're related). Check out the report ["Cottage Food Laws in the United States"](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/foodpolicyinitiative/files/2013/08/FINAL_Cottage-Food-Laws-Report_2013.pdf) from Harvard Law School, or [this report on the California Cottage Food Bill](http://www.mountainfeed.com/blogs/learn/15522693-how-to-sell-your-homemade-food-start-a-home-based-food-business-under-the-cottage-food-bill-ab1616). Basically, with limitations, you can create and sell "non-hazardous" foods in home kitchens, but the phrase "non-hazardous" means different things in different jurisdictions. For instance, the Harvard Law report says that the 2009 FDA Code lists the following as potentially hazardous foods:

> meat, poultry, and eggs; fish and shellfish; cooked vegetables; dairy products; mushrooms; cut melons; unmodified cut tomatoes or mixtures of cut tomatoes; untreated garlic‐in‐oil mixtures; baked goods subject to spoilage (such as cream‐ filled pastries or others that must be refrigerated); reduced sugar jams and jellies; pickles and salsa; and, raw seed sprouts.

The basic theory seems to be that "cottage foods" must be intrinsically safe, so that even with poor preparation and storage they won't result in a dangerous product. So, even if you could make your salad dressing safely, if someone could potentially NOT make it safely then it probably wouldn't be considered a legal "cottage food".

The California Department of Public Health gives a [long list of approved foods](http://www.cdph.ca.gov/programs/Documents/fdbCFOfoodslist.pdf), and none of them match your dressing idea.

The Wikipedia article gives the primary ingredients of Miracle Whip as [water, soybean oil, vinegar, high fructose corn syrup, sugar, modified corn starch, and dried eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_Whip#Ingredients). It also includes [potassium sorbate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_sorbate), but I'd still be concerned about the resulting product's safety, and your lawyer may as well.

(Not a lawyer or a food safety expert, YMMV, void where prohibited, use no hooks, etc. etc. etc.)